# File upload controller not working after upload - global.asax not firing after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, global-asax

I have a problem with fileuploadController. On my local computer it works perfectly. Uploading without problem. But when I publish site and upload to web its not uploading and getting error not found.

Here is the my local computer result
[image]

And here is the web version
[image]

and my Globax.Asax file is like that

```html
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
            {
                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "DefaultApi",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
                    );

                
            });
```

I tried everything but no success. What can I do to fix this problem.

Comment: First, check if the path to the file is there on the server, then try to display the path you are trying to acces in a window or in a text file, if your file is bigger than 4 mb then look at user3698428's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your routeTemplate to:

"../api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

Answer (score 1):

If you are uploading more than 4MB size file, then IIS will reject the request. You can increase it by changing your web.config file

```
<system.web>
  <!-- To allow upto 1 GB -> 1*1024*1024 = 1048576 -->
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"  />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <!-- To allow upto 1 GB -> 1*1024*1024*1024 = 1073741824 -->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/83/Aspnet-maximum-file-upload-size-limit.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old, but look if you have a Precompiledapp.config file in the project.

I've found that deleting this file solved it as the routing in global.asax wasn't being done with that file in the project.